# Prove that if $[a]^s = [1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, for some $s \in \mathbb{N}$, then $[a]^t \not = [0]$, for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $[a]^s = [1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}m$, for some $s \in \mathbb{N}$, then $[a]^t  \not = [0]$, for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$.

So far my approach are as follows

When trying the forward direction all i get is that $a^s-1=m(x), x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then you can write $1$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $m$ so thus $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Thus $[a] \not = 0$ so $[a]^t \not =0$

With the contrapositve I tried

So if  $[a]^t = [0]$ implies that $[a]=0$ thus $[a]^s = [1]$ in $\mathbb{Z}m$ is only true if $m=1$. I didn't properly deal with the quantifiers though so I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Write $ns = t+k$ for some $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $[a]^{ns} = [1]^n = [1]$ is a multiple of $[a]^t$ and thus $[a]^t \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because $[a]\ne 0$ that $[a]^t\ne 0$. For instance, in $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$, $[6]^3=0$, albeit $[6]\ne0$.

You can observe that if $[a]^s=1$, $[a]$ is a unit in the ring  $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z$, with inverse $[a]^{s-1}$. Suppose $[a]^{t}=0$ for some $t$.

You have $[a]^{t}=[a]^{t\bmod s}$, so you can suppose $t<s$. But then
$$[a]^{s}=1=[a]^{t}[a]^{s-t}=0\cdot[a]^{s-t}=0,$$
which is a contradiction.